# On IE11 Windows 8.1, button remains highlighted after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a (relatively) complex web application, and encountering a very specific issue. On the specific OS and Browser mentioned in the title, in one of the forms that shows up, when some buttons are clicked, they remain "highlighted" as if the mouse were still hovering over them, even when the mouse leaves the button element or if the user clicks on a separate element on the page. It looks like this:

[image: The Problem Image]

(the "First Name", "Last Name", etc. elements are the buttons)

The specific behavior of these buttons is that when they are clicked, they put a specific bit of text into the text form shown, then focus the text form. This is done using some standard jQuery functions (.val(), .focus(), etc.) On any OS/browser pair I have seen other than Win8.1/IE11, this does not happen. (it doesn't happen on Win7/IE11 even!) And as far as I can tell, there are no other handlers attached to the buttons than click, and the only styles that seem to be applied have to do with size, color, and text.

Honestly, I'm completely stumped about this behavior. I've even tried doing things as making sure to call .blur() on the button, trigger mouseout events, etc. and nothing seems to make a dent in this. The only thing that seems to cause the highlighting to go away is to click very close to the buttons, but not on them, or to drag-select some text.

**EDIT December 7, 2015**: This has been on my backburner for a while with other more-pressing issues to deal with. But I'm going to do my best to provide a nice update with more information so that this can hopefully be resolved. (assuming this isn't some browser bug in the specific version of IE on Windows 8.1)

I have verified that the only event handler attached to the button is an onclick handler defined in the HTML itself by checking what IE11's dev tools see as the event handlers on the element:

```
<input type="button" value="${someValue}" onclick="autoText('${token}');"/>
```

`autotext` is a very simple function that does what is described above, but here is the actual source code for it:

```
function autoText(token) {
  if(null != lastFocus) {
    var str = lastFocus.val(),
        tokenStr = '$\{' + token + '\}',
        newStr = str.substring(0, pos) +
          tokenStr + str.substring(pos, str.length);
    lastFocus.val(newStr);
    var lastPos = pos + tokenStr.length;
    lastFocus.focus();
    lastFocus.caret(lastPos);
    lastFocus.keypress();
}
```

where `lastFocus` is set to the text input element that was last focused and pos is set to where the caret is in the text input element.

The button that has the onclick listener is in the following hierarchy, as given to me by Chrome: `html` -> `body` -> `div` -> `div#templateFormDiv` -> `form#prefsEmailTemplatesSave` -> `table` -> `tbody` -> `tr` -> `td` -> `input` (where -> indicates it is the parent)

- `html` has the classes `mod-js mod-canvas mod-no-touch mod-postmessage mod-contenteditable mod-cookies mod-filereader mod-formvalidation mod-fileinput mod-formattribute mod-getusermedia`
- `body` has no CSS classes
- `div` has `ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable`
- `div#templateFormDiv` has the classes `hidden preferencesDialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content`
- `form#prefsEmailTemplatesSave` has the class `savePrefsForm`
- `table`, `tbody`, `tr`, `td`, and `input` don't have any classes associated with them.

The CSS rules for all the listed classes, ids, and tags are as follows:

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    color: #333;
}
form {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

All other classes, as far as I can tell, are included as part of bits of jQuery or are there as markers for DOM queries. (e.g.: savePrefsForm)

- `div#templateFormDiv` has a dialog attached to it via a jQuery `dialog()` call.
- `form.savePrefsForm` is selected and all found elements have an ajaxForm attached to them via jQuery. In a similar vein, `#prefsEmailTemplatesSave` is selected and submitted if the `#templateFormDiv` dialog has its save button pressed and it passes some validation logic.

The last thing I can think of to note here is that there is a TinyMCE editable text area next to where the buttons are. No parent/child relationship, but rather a sibling one.

I'll try to think of any further details that matter and include them if I do, otherwise I'll just answer any further questions that anyone has about what is going on.

Comment: can you share a fiddle? how did you implement the style change?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't actually any style changes being done by the web page. The buttons are just stock input type=button elements. The only bit of customization is an onclick=customfun('text') in the HTML itself, which does as described above. (add text to an input field, focus the field)

Answer (score 2):

Have same issue on IE 9-11 Windows 8.1-10. Every button that not cause postback, remains highlighted after click. On the other sites buttons work properly, so it was clearly my issue. I found it because CSS selector "hover" in my styles:
.navigationLink:hover {
}
I have changed it to:
a.navigationLink:hover {
}
and now buttons highlighting works properly. I can't understand what kind of magic is it. Any help would be appreciated.